# updating dconf doesnt change commands

Tags: cinnamon, dconf

I just updated dconf from a stored settings file using `dconf load /org/cinnamon/ < keyboard_shortcuts_export_dconf` I then made some changes to the file (exchanging `firefox` for `google-chrome`) and tried to import the file using the same command. It didnt give an error, but the changes did not take effect (when I use a shortcut it still opens in firefox). Is there some kind of `source` command for dconf I have to use to refresh the file or something?

```
[/]
panels-autohide=['1:false']
panels-resizable=['1:true']
enabled-applets=['panel1:left:0:menu@cinnamon.org:0', 'panel1:left:1:show-desktop@cinnamon.org:1', 'panel1:left:2:panel-launchers@cinnamon.org:2', 'panel1:left:3:window-list@cinnamon.org:3', 'panel1:right:0:notifications@cinnamon.org:4', 'panel1:right:1:user@cinnamon.org:5', 'panel1:right:2:removable-drives@cinnamon.org:6', 'panel1:right:3:keyboard@cinnamon.org:7', 'panel1:right:4:bluetooth@cinnamon.org:8', 'panel1:right:5:network@cinnamon.org:9', 'panel1:right:6:sound@cinnamon.org:10', 'panel1:right:7:power@cinnamon.org:11', 'panel1:right:8:systray@cinnamon.org:12', 'panel1:right:9:calendar@cinnamon.org:13', 'panel1:right:10:windows-quick-list@cinnamon.org:14', 'panel1:right:0:workspace-switcher@cinnamon.org:15']
next-applet-id=16
panel-launchers=['DEPRECATED']
panels-height=['1:31']

[settings-daemon/plugins/xsettings]
antialiasing='rgba'
hinting='slight'

[settings-daemon/peripherals/touchpad]
motion-threshold=3
natural-scroll=true
motion-acceleration=3.1529411764705881
scroll-method='two-finger-scrolling'
two-finger-click=3
three-finger-click=2
touchpad-enabled=true

[settings-daemon/peripherals/keyboard]
numlock-state='off'

[desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom2]
binding=['<Super>d']
command='google-chrome "drive.google.com"'
name='drive'

[desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom1]
binding=['<Super>e']
command='google-chrome "https://inbox.google.com/?pli=1"'
name='email'

[desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom4]
binding=['<Super>Down']
command='xrandr --output eDP1 --rotate normal'
name='rotate screen normal'

[desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom0]
binding=['<Super>c']
command='google-chrome "https://www.google.com"'
name='chrome'

[desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom3]
binding=['<Super>Up']
command='xrandr --output eDP1 --rotate right'
name='rotate screen right'

[desktop/keybindings]
custom-list=['custom0', 'custom1', 'custom2', 'custom4', 'custom3', 'custom5']

[desktop/keybindings/media-keys]
terminal=['<Super>t']
home=['XF86Explorer']

[desktop/keybindings/wm]
push-tile-up=@as []
switch-to-workspace-left=['<Super>Left']
switch-to-workspace-right=['<Super>Right']
maximize-vertically=['<Primary>Right']
show-desktop=['<Primary>d']
push-tile-left=@as []
push-tile-right=@as []
push-tile-down=@as []

[desktop/background]
picture-uri='file:///home/king/Desktop/image3.png'

[desktop/interface]
text-scaling-factor=1.5000000000000004

[sounds]
login-enabled=false
logout-enabled=false
unplug-enabled=true
tile-enabled=false
switch-enabled=false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not sure how to fix this correctly, but rebooting seems to reload dconf. If someone has an actual answer I will accept that instead, but the simple fix seems to be: reboot the machine